# To scroll custom tableview with text field in swift

Tags: swift, tableview, scrollview, textfield

[image]

In my swift project i have a textfield with a dropbox option. when i click on the dropbox a custom tableview opens. When i scroll the view the textfield is scrolling but the tableview fixed at the same place. how to scroll the tableview with the textfield? can anyone help me ?

here is my code:-

```
  @IBAction func dropdownButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        configureUi()
    }
 
    
    private func configureUi(){
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(LocationTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuserIdentifier)
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: superStackView.arrangedSubviews[6].frame.origin.y + 25 + superStackView.frame.origin.y, width: proffessionalTextField.frame.width, height: 200)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
```

Comment: adding an image describe your current situation may help people understand correctly

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: Are you adding the table view as a Textfield subview or as a Parent UIView subview?

Comment: my textfield is inside a stackview. and i am adding the tableview as a subview of uiview

Comment: why not  using a UIPickerView ?